How can I get the program_id from the last transaction response Solana Blockchain Rust
I have a code
fn main() {
let rpc_url = String::from("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/");
let client = RpcClient::new(rpc_url);
let pk = Pubkey::from_str("adresshere").unwrap();

let signatures = client.get_signatures_for_address(&pk).unwrap();

if let Some(last_signature) = signatures.first() {

    let signature = Signature::from_str(&last_signature.signature).unwrap();
    let trx = client.get_transaction(
        &signature,
        UiTransactionEncoding::JsonParsed
    ).unwrap();

    match trx.transaction.transaction {
        EncodedTransaction::Json(json) => {
            match json.message {
                UiMessage::Parsed(message) => {
                    //println!("{:?}", &message.instructions[0]);
                    match &message.instructions[0] {
                        UiInstruction::Parsed(inst) => {
                            match inst {
                                UiParsedInstruction::Parsed(d) => {
                                    println!("{:?}", d);
                                }
                                _ => panic!()
                            }
                        }
                        _ => panic!()
                    }
                }
                _ => panic!()
            }
        }
        _ => panic!()
    }

} else {
    println!("Not found");
}

}
But I'm having trouble getting the program_id. I walk JSON response and using struct and enum-methods from solana_transaction_status I get the answers
Please help

I faced with the same problem, is there any more elegant way to solve the problem?

You're very close! Once you get to UiParsedInstruction::Parsed(d), the program_id is right there, so you can do:
                                UiParsedInstruction::Parsed(d) => {
                                    println!("{:?}", d.program_id);
                                }

The source code for ParsedInstruction exists at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/b0cfffb290051d8c8a42923eca1459e3bba4cef2/transaction-status/src/parse_instruction.rs#L82
